# generic types in knockout without using "any"

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I was wondering if there is any way to make a generic variable without use the KnockoutObservableAny

I would like to do something like `KnockoutObservable<SomeType>() = new Sometype()`

I know this is possible for arrays

[KnockoutObservableArray with typed elements in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914512/knockoutobservablearray-with-typed-elements-in-typescript)

but I couldn't find a way to do this for regular variables.

Comment: So are you using typescript or javascript? That doesn't apply to javascript...

Comment: What type definitions are you using? Self made? The one on [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/knockout/knockout.d.ts) appears to have all you would need.

Answer (score 1):

couple examples:

```
interface Chicken {
   eggs: number;
}

var x: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable(''),
    y: KnockoutObservable<Chicken> = ko.observable(),
    z: KnockoutObservable<Chicken> = ko.observable({ eggs: 6 });
```